# Please help me identify LEGO set

Tags: set-identification

I bought used set (75301) but the bricks seems not to belong to the set actually.
Could you please help me to identify the right set?

I am very grateful for any help :-)

[image: picture of the bricks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the 4x4 radar dish in dark blue from the top-left bag (and a bit of digging), the **top two bags** seem to be consistent with set [75283 Armored Assault Tank](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75283-1):

[image: Set 75283]

The 2x2 light grey tile with the insignia, however, should be a sticker instead of a printed tile (according to the parts list for the set):

[image: 2x2 tile with insignia]

---

Based on parts [Aircraft Fuselage Forward Bottom Curved 6 x 10 with 3 Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?P=87611) and [Technic, Axle Connector Block Round with 2 Pin Holes and 3 Axle Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?P=98585) , the **two bottom bags** can be identified as part of [set 75314 The Bad Batch Attack Shuttle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75314-1):

[image: set 75314]

Note the fuselage part and the sheer amount of technic connectors in the bottom right bag. Also, note part [98834pb30 Vehicle, Spoiler with Bar Handle with Black Outline Bolts on Sand Blue Background Pattern (Sticker)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98834pb30) in the bottom left bag:

[image: part 98834pb30]

Why you have stickered parts in seemingly sealed bags, and why is there a 2x2 tile with separatist insignia in the bottom left bag, I cannot tell.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts Ivan it was very helpful!